# Right-associativity in type signatures of functions

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, currying, type-signature

I've troubles understanding the reasoning behind types signatures in Haskell.

1) as `->` is said to be right associative, does it mean that it could be understood in the similar way as, for example 4^(2^(3^2))?

2) using type signature of simple function so as to express my doubts (to explain the way I understand it, I'll use `a`,`b`,`c` instead of `Num a => a`'s or `Int`'s):

```
myAdd :: a -> b -> c
myAdd x y = x+y
```

It means that function takes parameter `a` and returns function that takes `b` and finally returns `c`

But it could be re-written as:

```
myAdd :: (a->(b->c))
```

As most of the learning material states that `c` in our example is the result of function myAdd, why according to the use of brackets it indicates that first 'operation' is `b->c`? How do I deduce from that type signature the order of performed operations?

3) I was given a task to implement

```
map f xs
```

using  `foldr`, `(.)`, and `(:)` which resulted in:

```
map f xs = foldr ((:) . f) [] xs
```

I've no problems understanding the workings of the above functions, but here we come again - type signatures. If we assume, that names are unified so type `a` represents the same type in all contracts, it seems, that `c` and `d` can be expressed in terms of `a` and `b`. In mathematics, similar task would be probably quite straightforward, but how do I approach it in Haskell?

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
foldr :: (a -> c -> c) -> c -> [a] -> c
(:) :: b -> ([b] -> [b])
(.) :: (b -> d) -> (a -> b) -> a -> d
```

Comment: Please focus your question on one properly answerable aspect.

Comment: The operation involved in part 1 is creating a function type. The function type created "first" is `b -> c`. This is then combined into the larger function type `a -> (b -> c)`. Note that all of this is at the level of types, not at the level of values. `->` is something that takes in two types and gives you back a type: the type of functions from the left type to the right type. To make things more a little more concrete, if you give `->` the types `Char` and `Int`, it gives you back the type of functions from `Char` to `Int`.

Answer (score 8):

Using your notation, in

```
myAdd :: a -> b -> c
myAdd x y = x+y
```

you correctly interpret the type as `a -> (b->c)` but then you go on to suggest that the computation in `b -> c` is somehow done first.

When something like `myAdd 2 10` is evaluated, the function evaluation is left to right.

1) First `myAdd 2` is evaluated. The result of this evaluation is the function which sends a given number `y` to `2 + y`. In effect, the definition of `myAdd` is the same as

```
myAdd x = \y -> x+y
```

2) This last function is then applied to the argument `10` to yield `2 + 10 = 12`

Thus, the right associativity of `->` in the *type expression* doesn't correspond to a right to left ordering of computation in the *function evaluation*. In fact, function evaluation is left-associative: `myAdd 2 10` is the same as `(myAdd 2) 10`.

Comment: I do understand left-associativity of function evaluation, but don't right-associativity of '->' in the type expression.

Comment: Type expressions say what something *is* -- they don't specify order  of computation. `a -> (b ->c)` says that an element of type `a` maps to something which `is` a function which sends elements of type `b` to elements of type `c`. Think of it as logical grouping of constituent parts, not temporal grouping of computation.

Answer (score 0):

Saying the term "right-associativity" to indicate the invisible-by-default parentheses by currying here in type signatures is quite misleading.

As in cases of mathematics, same symbols indicate different meanings and usages in different fields and studies.

The explicit or invisible parentheses don't indicate associativity like they'd be in terms of arithmetic precedence.

Which in arithmetic, the calculation of the innermost parentheses evaluates first towards the calculation of the outermost parentheses.

Whereas in the type system of Haskell, parentheses indicate nothing else but a function returned by another function taking the argument of the previous type before the "->" notation, which is a function that takes an argument of the type after the "->" notation and then returns another function, and so forth, till a certain function returns the final result.

For example:
Let's say we define a function that takes three arguments of types constrained in the typeclass "Num" that sums up all the given numbers.

```
-- without explicit parentheses
sumThreeNums :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
sumThreeNums n1 n2 n3 = n1 + n2 + n3

-- with explicit parentheses
sumThreeNums :: Num a => (a -> (a -> (a -> a)))
sumThreeNums n1 n2 n3 = n1 + n2 + n3
```

When loading the second example with explicit parentheses from a file in ghci, it's compiled successfully.

Here the type reasoning "(a -> (a -> (a -> a)))" indicates that the function "sumThreeNums" first takes the first argument of type "a" and returns another function,

which is "(a -> (a -> a))", that takes the second argument of type "a" and returns another function,

which is "(a -> a)", that takes the third argument of type "a", and returns the final result of the type "a".

In practice, explicit parentheses are often used to indicate that the argument is a function, and the process of currying which I showed above, is omitted of parentheses by default.

Here it is, happy hacking :)